# TestControllerConfigUI - Failed to update service account VSTTController (Error Code: 1355) error

Tags: automated-tests

Hi I am getting the following error on Test Controller tool, i am on windows 10

```
E, 2016/06/01, 12:32:58.069, Failed to update service account of windows service VSTTController. (Error Code: 1355)
```

and i dont have groups available in this version on windows 10

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this console. 
1. Run Computer management console. Click start button and type mmc. Run it with Admin privileges
In Microsoft Management Console, click the File menu, and then click Add/Remove Snap-in.

Click Local Users and Groups, and then click Add.

Click Local computer, click Finish, and then click OK.
Add your user to Team Test Controller Admin and Team Test Controller Users.
Depends on Your configuration your might Add these groups first

Comment: Thanks Vitalii but this version of windows 10 does not allow me add Local Users and Groups.